# How to compare row by row with some extra conditions?

Tags: sas

I have some consumer data that tells where the consumer shops the data has more rows with different consumer ids but for testing purposes I have included chunk of that data

```
ConsumerID  Retailer    Product_Code     Shopping_Date    
    1       Wallmart    12345            20090721
    1       Wallmart    12345            20090722
    1       Bestbuy     23456            20090801
    1       Bestbuy         23456            20090801  
    1       Bestbuy         23456            20090801
    1       Bestbuy         23456            20090801
    1       Frys            23444            20090908
```

Basically **if the retailer is not the same and product code is not the same the consumer has switched retailers and products** for example the first row and the second row have the same retailer so they **would not count in the new data set**. **The new data set that I want to create should contain fromretailer toretailer, if the Shopping_date is the same then that is counted as one occasion**, **but when we display the final result it still shows 4 transcations so the person goes from wallmart to bestbuy 4 times. Then when the person switches from Bestbuy to frys its again 4 times because besbuy had 4 transactions.

So my new data should look like this

```
ConsumerID  FromRetailer ToRetailer    FromDate        ToDate      FP
        1   Wallmart     BestBuy        20090722       20090801    1/4
        1   Wallmart     BestBuy        20090722       20090801    1/4
        1   Wallmart     BestBuy        20090722       20090801    1/4
        1   Wallmart     BestBuy        20090722       20090801    1/4
        1   Bestbuy      Frys           20090722       20090908    1/4
        1   Bestbuy      Frys           20090722       20090908    1/4
        1   Bestbuy      Frys           20090722       20090908    1/4
        1   Bestbuy      Frys           20090722       20090908    1/4
```

FP is basically how many times the person switched in this case they switched from one time to 4 times this can change the go from 2 times to 4 times which would make the FP 1/8

My main issue is how would I firstly compare the  first row with the second row then the next issue is for example if the second row has the same date then it is classified as one occasion so the consumer goes from wall mart to Best buy 4 times.

More explanation

```
1       Wallmart    12345            20090721
1       Wallmart    23456            20090722
1       Wallmart    23456            20090821
```

The output should be

```
   Consumer_ID  From_Store   To_Store          From_Porduct    To_Product  FP
    1             Wallmart     Wallmart         12345           23456        1
```

Explanation:
There are two types of switches Product switch and Store switch so the condition for a switch should be if retailer!=retailer2 or productCode!=productCode2 then its a switch (either product or store).

FP is calculated simply by  the switch count that is for example in the example above the consumer goes from wallmart to wallmart that is a one to one switch so therefore FP is one, but in the pervious example the person went from wallmart to besbuy which is 1/4 because they bought 4 items in best buy.

The Shopping_date is important because for examlple a person buys 4 items it becomes on shopping trip but when we display the data we still display 4 transactions the reason why I say it becomes one trip is so that we dont compare bestbuy with bestbuy as they occured on the same shopping_date.

So to sum up everything the data contains more than one consumer_id each consumer_id needs to be compared indicually so we group the Consumer_ID

then secondly we check if its a store switch or product switch if we have a store/product switch we compare the rows if the rows have the shooping date they are classified as one trip but we still display 4 transactions in the final output.
Sample Data

```
 1       Wallmart    12345            20090721
 1       Wallmart    23456            20090722
 1       Wallmart    23456            20090724
 1       Bestbuy     23456            20090801
 1       Bestbuy     23456            20090801
 1       Bestbuy     23456            20090801
 1       Bestbuy     23456            20090801
 1       Frys        3456             20090903
 2       Frys        12455            20090905
 2       Frys        3456             20090904
 2       Frys        3456             20090904
```

Output Data

```
Consumer_ID      From_Store     To_Store    From_Product   To_Product       From_Date        To_Date             FP   Type of Switch
1                Wallmart         Wallmart    12345        23456            20090721         20090724            1       Product_Switch
1                Wallart          Bestbuy     23456        23456            20090724         20090801            1/4     Store Switch
1                Wallart          Bestbuy     23456        23456            20090724         20090801            1/4     Store Switch
1                Wallart          Bestbuy     23456        23456            20090724         20090801            1/4     Store Switch
1                Wallart          Bestbuy     23456        23456            20090724         20090801            1/4     Store Switch
1                Bestbuy          Frys        23456        3456             20090801         20090903            1/4     Store Switch
1                Bestbuy          Frys        23456        3456             20090801         20090903            1/4     Store Switch
1                Bestbuy          Frys        23456        3456             20090801         20090903            1/4     Store Switch
1                Bestbuy          Frys        23456        3456             20090801         20090903            1/4     Store Switch
2                Frys             Frys        12455        3456             20090905         20090904            1       Store_Switch
```

NOTES: Each Consumer's are treated different we dont compare the consumers transcations with anohter consumer we essentialy group consumers. I hope this helps we dont need type of switch I put it there for understanding

Some code that I have written

```
data work.switches;
 set work.consumerData;


 from_retailer=lag(retialer);
 to_retailer=retialer;
 from_product_code=lag(product_code);
 to_product_code=product_code;
 if from_retailer ne to_retailer or from_product ne to_product then 
    do i=1 by 1 until (last.trip_date);



      /*Not sure what to do here
       end;
run;
```

Comment: Have you put together any code to do this yet?

Comment: yeah you want me to post it

Comment: ESmith5988 posted my code but it does not do much atm

Comment: Thanks. It's good to see how you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this likely isn't the best or simplest solution, but I couldn't think of another way to go about this. Also, I don't think I am estimating your FP variable correctly...but maybe this can help you get what you need.

```
*Import data;
data consumerData;
    input Consumer_ID Store $ Product Date;
    datalines;
    1 Wallmart 12345 20090721
    1 Wallmart 12345 20090722
    1 Bestbuy 23456 20090801
    1 Bestbuy 23456 20090801
    1 Bestbuy 23456 20090801
    1 Bestbuy 23456 20090801
    1 Frys 23444 20090908
;
run;
*Make sure data sorted by consumer_id and date;
proc sort data=consumerData; BY Consumer_ID Date Store;

*total number of purchases made in a day. Get from dataset;
proc freq data=consumerData noprint;
    TABLE Consumer_ID*Store*Date/out=freq;
run;
proc sql noprint;
    select max(count) as totalPurch from freq;
quit;

data work.switches (Drop=Store Product Date product_: lagProd_: i j keep lagNObs NObs);
    length Type_of_Switch $30;
    set work.consumerData;
    BY Consumer_ID Date Store;

    *count number of records per shopping trip date (from same store);
    NObs+1;
    if first.Date and first.Store then NObs=1;

    *create array to hold different purchases from store on same date;
    retain product_1-product_&totalPurch;
    array arProduct[*] product_1-product_&totalPurch;
    do i=1 to &totalPurch;
        if NObs=i then arProduct[i]=Product;
        if NObs=1 then do j=2 to &totalPurch;
            arProduct[j]=.; *reset;
        end;
    end;

    *only keep one record for each shopping trip;
    if last.Date then keep=1;
    if keep^=1 then delete;

    *Compute From and To Store and Date Variables;
    From_Store=lag(Store);
    To_Store=Store;
    From_Date=lag(Date);
    To_Date=Date;

    *Get lagged Product Values;
    lagNObs=lag(NObs);*identify number of lagged purchases;
    array lagProd(*)lagProd_1-lagProd_&totalPurch;
    do i=1 to &totalPurch;
        lagProd[i]=lag(arProduct[i]);
    end;

    *Compute From and To Product Variables;
    do i=1 to NObs;
        if lagNObs^=. then do j=1 to lagNObs;
            From_Product=lagProd[j];
            To_Product=arProduct[i];
            FP=strip(lagNObs)||'/'||strip(Nobs);
            *Label Types of Switches;
            if From_Store ne To_Store then Type_of_Switch='Store Switch';
            if From_Product ne To_Product then Type_of_Switch='Product Switch';
            if (From_Product ne To_Product) and (From_Store ne To_Store) then Type_of_Switch='Product and Store Switch';
            if j>1 then output switches;
        end;
        if i>1 then output;
    end;

    *Delete first occurance so eliminate obs without lag;
    if first.Consumer_ID then delete;

    *Output switches;
    if (From_Store ne To_Store) or (From_Product ne To_Product) then output;
run;
```

Comment: Hey I don't really have time to actually write it out, but I can tell you that the way to handle this is with BY groups and RETAIN (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761932.htm and http://changchung.com/download/retainLagLeadInterleave_draft.pdf and http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/104-28.pdf will all explain more). All in all this should be a short command... a proc sort followed by about 10 lines or so in the DATA step... I can follow up tonight with the code if you can't figure it from the documentation on BY and RETAIN

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a simpler solution. I did this quickly and kept adding once I figured out more about what the poster wanted. I couldn't think of a quick way to make BY processing handle what I am doing through arrays.

Comment: thank you so much thank you so much honestly this great help. Btw does your code account for more ConsumerIDS

Comment: @ArcCoder - It should. If it isn't working properly then let me know and I can probably update the code as needed.

Comment: @ESmith5988 thanks so much there are some things which code does not handle if there are more consumers it works but it compares the previous consumers purchases. Also if there are more then 4 purchases then the code deos not work you can change the by updating totalPurchases but is there anyway of doing it dynamically. So far your code is doing what I want just some more cases, if you need examples for those cases let me know.

Comment: @ArcCoder - Yes, there are ways to make it dynamic and to fix the problems you're having. I'll try to take a look at it again later today. Can you update your code to contain an example with more consumers?

Comment: @ArcCoder - I updated the code to dynamically get the number of total purchases on any given day. I added another sample consumer to the dataset and I'm not finding any issues. Particularly, I am not seeing any comparisons to a previous consumer's purchases. Please update with specific examples.

Comment: ESmith yeah your code works thank you so much I really appreciate it